# Click event not getting triggered after Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax call that gets triggered after the document is loaded, Just below the ajax call I have submit event for the submit button...

The click event does not get triggered if the stmt alert("New Start") is removed. I'm sure there is bug in the ajax call but not sure what is it?

```
$.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",
               url:"/getresponse/",
                data:{},
               context:this,
               success:function(response){
                   //event.preventDefault()

                    console.log("Value of response =" + response['table_appl']['IPTEXT'])


                    var vms = ['appl','enfr','det01','det02','det03','det04','det05','datais']

                    vms.forEach(function(i){
                        var header;
                        switch ( i ) 
                        {
                            case 'appl':
                                header = "APPL"
                                break;
                            case 'enfr':
                                header = "EN"
                                break;
                            case 'det01':
                                header = "D01"
                                break;
                            case 'det02':
                                header = "D02"
                                break;
                            case 'det03':
                                header = "D03"
                                break;
                            case 'det04':
                                header = "D04"
                                break;
                            case 'det05':
                                header = "D05"
                                break;
                            case 'datais':
                                header = "DT"
                                break;
                        }
                        //console.log("Value of response =" + response['table_appl']['IPTEXT'])
                        //value = ' + response['table_' + i + ']['IPTEXT']
                        //console.log("  Main loop IP      =" + response['table_'+ i ]['IPTEXT'] ) 
                        iptext = response['table_'+ i ]['IPTEXT']
                        dns1text = response['table_'+ i ]['DNS1TEXT']
                        dns2text = response['table_'+ i ]['DNS2TEXT']
                        gwtext = response['table_'+ i ]['GWTEXT']
                        nmtext = response['table_'+ i ]['NMTEXT']
                        ntp1text = response['table_'+ i ]['NTP1TEXT']
                        ntp2text = response['table_'+ i ]['NTP2TEXT']
                        id1text = response['table_'+ i ]['ID1TEXT']
                        hosttext = response['table_'+ i ]['HOSTTEXT']

                        if (!iptext){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            iptext = ''
                        }

                        if (!dns1text){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            dns1text = ''
                        }

                        if (!dns2text){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            dns2text = ''
                        }
                        if (!gwtext){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            gwtext = ''
                        }
                        if (!nmtext){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            nmtext = ''
                        }
                        if (!ntp1text){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            ntp1text = ''
                        }
                        if (!ntp2text){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            ntp2text = ''
                        }
                        if (!hosttext){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            hosttext = ''
                        }
                        if (!id1text){
                            //console.log("Its null")
                            id1text = ''
                        }

                        console.log('iptext = ' +iptext)

                        $('#div2').append('<div id=\'div2' + i + '\'>');
                        $('#div2' + i + '').addClass('box');

                        $('#div2' + i + '').append('<h2>' + header + '</h2>');

                        $('#div2' + i + '').append('<table id=\'table_' + i + '\' cellspacing=\'20\'></table>');
                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'ipaddresslabel\'>IPADDRESS</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'IP\'  value =\'' + iptext + '\' >  </td> <td> <label id=\'DISPLAYIP\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'dns1label\'>DNS1</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'DNS1\' value =\'' + dns1text + '\' > </td> <td> <label id=\'DISPLAYDNS1\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'dns2label\'>DNS2</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'DNS2\' value =\'' + dns2text + '\' > </td> <td> <label id=\'DISPLAYDNS2\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'gwlabel\'>GATEWAY</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'GW\' value =\'' + gwtext + '\'> </td> <td> <label id=\'DISPLAYGW\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'nmlabel\'>NETMASK</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'NM\' value =\'' + nmtext + '\'> </td> <td> <label id=\'DISPLAYNM\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'ntp1label\'>NTPSERVER1</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'NTP1\' value =\'' + ntp1text + '\'> </td> <td> <label id=\'DISPLAYNTP1\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'ntp2label\'>NTPSERVER2</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'NTP2\' value =\'' + ntp2text + '\'><td> <label id=\'DISPLAYNTP2\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'hostlabel\'>HOSTNAME</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'HOST\' value =\'' + hosttext + '\'> </td> <td> <label id=\'DISPLAYHOST\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td> <label for=\'idlabel\'>INTERNAL DOMAIN</label> </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type=\'text\' name=\'ID1\' value =\'' + id1text + '\'> </td> <td> <label id=\'DISPLAYID1\' for=\'success\' style="DISPLAY:none">Validated</label> </td></tr>');

                        $('#table_' + i + '').append('<tr><td>  </td>' +
                        '<td> <input type="submit" value=\'save\' id=\'sub' + i + '\' /></td> <td>  </td></tr>');

                        //$('#div2' + i + '').append('<div id=\'div2' + i + 'footer\'>');

                        //$('#div2' + i + 'footer').append('<input type="submit" value=\'save\' id=\'sub' + i + '\' />')
                    }
                    );

                    $('#div2enfr').hide();
                    $('#div2det01').hide();
                    $('#div2det02').hide();
                    $('#div2det03').hide();
                    $('#div2det04').hide();
                    $('#div2det05').hide();
                    $('#div2datais').hide();

                    alert('End')


                }

        })

//alert("New Start")

$("#table_appl,#table_enfr,#table_det01,#table_det02,#table_det03,#table_det04,#table_det05,#table_datais").on( "click", "input:submit", 
                function( event ) {
```

Comment: provide us code on fidlle

Comment: You may want to take a step back and think about ways to improve your algorithm. All those if statements and switches can surely be optimized?

Comment: You should also consider using ending semi-colon: this is javascript

Comment: You have missing `}` somewhere, does not validate in editor. Regarding semicolon: http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding

Comment: I cant provide the fiddle, since i get the response from server..

Comment: how can I find the missing }..Is there a way to debug it.

Comment: @RUJordan: Any recommendation to improve the if and switch stmt

Comment: Do you not have an editor Sublime Text or so? http://www.sublimetext.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a bug with the AJAX call, there's just a misconception about the order the code executes in. I assume the AJAX calls response is used to create the elements that the event handler is then bound to.

With the `alert` statement in there, the execution likely looks like this:

1. Send AJAX request
2. Alert (blocks the rest of that code until closed)
3. Receive response to AJAX request
4. Create elements
5. Bind event handler when alert box is closed

Without the `alert` statement, the execution looks like this:

1. Send AJAX request
2. Bind event handler
3. Receive response to AJAX request
4. Create elements

You obviously want 2 to happen *after* 4, so move it to the end of the `success` callback for your AJAX call. Alternatively modify your delegated event handler code so that it looks for an element that does definitely exist before the AJAX request completes, which would also require you to modify the selector passed as the second argument to `.on()`.

Comment: Anthony:The bind event is not part of the success..Its separate from it

Comment: My logic is 1.Send Ajax request...2.Receive response ...3.Create elements...4.Bind event...

Comment: @user1050619 Yes, I know. That's what I'm saying the problem is, that it's separate and therefore not being delayed until the AJAX request (which it sounds like it depends on) completes, except in the case where you have the alert blocking further execution.

Comment: @user1050619 No, that's what you *think* your logic is, but that's not how it works. If you want to guarantee something happens *after* the AJAX request, it needs to go in the `success` handler. That is how AJAX works.

Comment: I have too many events to put inside the success handler..Is there a way to wait for the AJAX response request and then bind it?

Comment: @user1050619 Put the event bindings in a separate function and just call that at the end of the success handler then.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Ajax call is asynchronous so if you use any information from ajax response in event handle, it is high possibility that such information is not available yet. Alert is just to "consume" the time for the ajax call gets completed.

You can try to use sync mode in ajax call to see whether it works.